# Is James stable for production use?

Tags: apache-2.2, email, email-server

[James](http://james.apache.org/server/index.html) is mail server written in pure Java and developed under the auspices of the Apache Software Foundation.

Is it stable enough for handling large (unpredictably large) amounts of mail? Can it be used by a hosting provider without fear of losing data? Are there any limitations?

Comment: Hello Artyom:  Did you ever deploy James Mail server on your production environment?  I am interesting in using it to handle my bounces.  I will appreciate your response.  Thanks.

Comment: Hello Geo. Sorry for late response. I never deployed James Mail server on production environment. I wasn't sure It would be stable. As people suggested below, better to adopt another MTAs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't touch it with a barge pole.  The one customer I've had using it had nothing but problems with it, frequently dying and causing problems with other things running on the machine.  There are plenty of other, less sucky, MTAs out there.

Comment: Seconded. Most MTAs are a pain anyway, there's no need to actually go *looking* for more of that.

Comment: Do you know of a good java based one?

Comment: What's this obsession with having an MTA that's written in Java?

Comment: Might be an integration project. However, shipping a Java MTA when there are better alternatives is irresponsible to say the least. Writing a well performing and secure MTA is very, very hard and takes years. There is no way anyone has written a Java MTA that lives up to the quality of one of the established ones.

Comment: The main reason would be to use a non-standard mail store.